# is there any chances to get the statusbar tinted on iPad (iOS 6)?

Tags: ipad, ios6, colors, statusbar, tint

iOS 6 provided statusbar tinted on iPhone, **but I cant find it on iPad**

I tried to modify [SBApplication StatusBarStyle] and other [StatusBarStyle]'s value to "1" via **FLEX** (*Cydia plugin*), and after I enabled these tweaks, any App's 1st launch, I can see the StatusBar is tinted with color

however, after the App is fully started, statusbar went totally black

can anybody help me? thx a alot!